# How to get Y-axis value in Highcharts?

Tags: angular, highcharts

Basically I'm using the below code to format the tooltip, but the value of this.y is varying based on zoom level of the graph. What is the best way to get the exact value of y-axis.

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function () {
    console.log(this);
    return this.y;
  }
}
```

[image: Before Zooming in]

[image: Same point after zooming in]

Comment: Hi @pavan skipo, Could you demonstrate the problem on some live example? By default the `y` value should be constant and accurate.

Comment: ah okay let me make a js fiddle

Comment: Js fiddle is breaking if i give such large data, i'll find another way

Comment: You can create some random data or use for example `http://myjson.com/` service to load your data.